# ACE editor adding special characters

Tags: utf-8, editor, ace-editor

The use case is to display server logs in the UI built using Angular9.
I am using ACE editor to display text content received from server upon a http call and the server responds with recent 1000 lines of logs
To verify the content i did console.log() to view the text content in the chrome dev tool.
[Console output received from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XX9c.png)

While loading the same content to editor I notice special characters

[Ace editor content while using in text mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S09h.png)

Attached 2 screenshot to compare

HTML Content

```
  <div ace-editor #codeEditor style="min-height: 550px; width:100%; overflow: auto;"></div>
```

Typescript

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

import * as ace from 'ace-builds';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-json';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-beautify';

const THEME = 'ace/theme/github';
const LANG = 'ace/mode/text';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-editor',
  templateUrl: './text-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-editor.component.css']
})
export class TextEditorComponent {
  @ViewChild('codeEditor') codeEditorElmRef: ElementRef;
  private codeEditor: ace.Ace.Editor;

  @Input() textObject;
  @Input() readMode;

  data: any;
  mode: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    for (const properties of Object.keys(changes)) {
      if (properties == 'textObject') {
        const currentJSONObject = changes[properties];
        if (currentJSONObject.currentValue && currentJSONObject.firstChange == false)
          this.codeEditor.setValue(currentJSONObject.currentValue, -1);
        else
          this.data = currentJSONObject.currentValue
      }
      if (properties == 'readMode') {
        const currentReadMode = changes[properties];
        if (currentReadMode.firstChange == false)
          this.codeEditor.setReadOnly(currentReadMode.currentValue);
        else
          this.mode = currentReadMode.currentValue
      }
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const element = this.codeEditorElmRef.nativeElement;
    const editorOptions: Partial<ace.Ace.EditorOptions> = {
      highlightActiveLine: true,
      displayIndentGuides: true,
      highlightSelectedWord: true,
    };
    this.codeEditor = ace.edit(element, editorOptions);
    this.codeEditor.setTheme(THEME);
    this.codeEditor.getSession().setMode(LANG);
    this.codeEditor.setShowFoldWidgets(true);
    this.codeEditor.setHighlightActiveLine(true);
    this.codeEditor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    this.codeEditor.setReadOnly(this.readMode);
    this.codeEditor.navigateFileEnd();
    if (this.data)
      this.codeEditor.setValue(this.data, - 1);
    if (this.mode)
      this.codeEditor.setReadOnly(this.mode);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sameer, welcome to Stack overflow. Could you please elaborate your question

Comment: @Harshapps thanks Harsha, I have updated the question and described the problem statement. Could you please help me to identify whether I missing any ace editor **property** ?

Answer (score 0):

This are not characters added by ace, but color control characters sent by the terminal. If you do not want to display colors, and only want the text use the following function

```
var CSIRegexp;
function getCSIRegexp() {
  if (CSIRegexp) return CSIRegexp; 
  // http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/ansicode.txt

  var classes = {
    C0              :  "\\x00-\\x1F", //
    SPACE           :  "\\x20\\xA0" , // Always and everywhere a blank space
    G0              :  "\\x21-\\x7E", //
    Intermediate    :  "\\x20-\\x2F", //  !"#$%&'()*+,-./
    Parameters      :  "\\x30-\\x3F", // 0123456789:;<=>?
    Uppercase       :  "\\x40-\\x5F", // @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
    Lowercase       :  "\\x60-\\x7E", // `abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
    Alphabetic      :  "\\x40-\\x7E", // (all of upper and lower case)
    Delete          :  "\\x7F"      , // Always and everywhere ignored
    C1              :  "\\x80-\\x9F", // 32 additional control characters
    G1              :  "\\xA1-\\xFE", // 94 additional displayable characters
    Special         :  "\\xA0\\xFF" , // Same as SPACE and DELETE
    ESC             :  "\\x1b"      , // 
    Ignore          :  "\\x7F\\x00-\\x1F\\x80-\\x9F" // Delete|C0|C1
  };


  var g = /:ESC:(\[:Parameters:*:Intermediate:?:Alphabetic:?|:Intermediate:+:Parameters:|:Parameters:|:Lowercase:|)|[:Ignore:]/;

  var inBrackets = false;
  var source = g.source.replace(/(\\.)|([\[\]])|:(\w*):/g, function(_, esc, b, cls) {
    if (esc) return esc;
    if (b) {
      inBrackets = b == "[";
      return b;
    }
    if (!cls) return ":";
    var r = classes[cls];
    if (!/ESC|Delete|C0|C1/.test(cls)) {
      r += classes.Ignore;
    }
    if (!inBrackets && cls != "ESC")
      r = "[" + r + "]";
    return r;
  });

  return CSIRegexp = new RegExp(source, "g");
}
```

to remove control character before setting data to the editor

```
 this.codeEditor.setValue(this.data.replace(getCSIRegexp(), ""), - 1);
```

You can test it with the following call:

```
"\x1b[1mreal text\x1b[10m".replace(getCSIRegexp(), "")
```

Comment: this solution worked but now the text content is being displayed in single line, do this regex eliminates \n character? Workaround I did is replaced the \n with ~ and vise versa - this.codeEditor.setValue(this.data.replace(/\n/g, '~').replace(getCSIRegexp(), "").replace(/~/g, '\n'), 1);